# SQL ACCESS Subquery with extra AND condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this SQL query for Acccess 2013 but I would like to have an extra condition saying:

```
 WHERE CLASS = 'ECN'.
```

I can't find a way to integrate it into my existing query - hopefully someone can give me a hint.

```
    SELECT m.ID, m.PN, m.CLASS, m.ZAHL, (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM Table1 AS m2
        WHERE m2.PN = m.PN AND m2.ID <= m.ID
    ) AS IncByPN
FROM Table1 AS m
ORDER BY m.ID;
```

So I want the result table to only show rows where

```
   CLASS = 'ECN'
```

Comment: Does `WHERE m.CLASS = 'ECN'` not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT m.ID,
    m.PN,
    m.CLASS,
    m.ZAHL,
    Count(M2.id) AS IncByPN
FROM Table1 AS m
    INNER JOIN Table1 AS m2 ON m2.PN = m.PN AND m2.ID <= m.ID
WHERE m.CLASS='ECN'
GROUP BY m.ID, m.PN, m.CLASS, m.ZAHL
ORDER BY m.ID
```